# WSO2 IS-KM 5.11.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Where can I find the wso2 is-km 5.11.0
In below link

```
https://wso2.com/api-management/previous-releases/
```

there is only 5.10.0 Please provide the link for 5.11.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WSO2 Identity Server 5.11.0 will not be available in the link you have shared. You need to download it from the [official download page](https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management/). Click on the **TRY IT NOW** button and you'll see the installation options. You can download the zip archive from there.

You don't have the **prepackaged WSO2 Identity Server as a Key Manager 5.11.0** as you got in the [previous versions](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configuring-wso2-identity-server-as-a-key-manager/). You need to download the IS 5.11.0 and [configure it as IS-KM](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/).